# How to assign Background Image to an entry in xamarin forms for ios

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am trying to add background image to an entry in xamarin forms and i wrote code for rendering in ios and android. For android it is working and for ios it is not working.
Here I am sharing rendering code for ios:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof(ExtendedUsername), typeof(RenderingEntryuname))]
namespace ifind.iOS
{
public class RenderingEntryuname: EntryRenderer
{
    // Override the OnElementChanged method so we can tweak this renderer post-initial setup
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null) {

            Control.TextAlignment=UITextAlignment.Center;
            UIImage img=UIImage.FromFile("Images/newimg.jpg");
            Control.Background=img

        }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the `UITextEntry` used for a Forms `Entry` will have its border style set to `UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect` and thus any background will be ignored.

Set the border style to none and your image will show up:

```
if (Control != null) {
   Control.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;
   Control.TextAlignment=UITextAlignment.Center;
   UIImage img=UIImage.FromFile("Images/newimg.jpg");
   Control.Background=img
}
```

> If the value is set to the UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect style, the custom background image associated with the text field is ignored.

Ref: [UITextField](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/index.html)

Comment: Thanks for your response.Now I changed my code and tested and it is working fine.